# Duda con selector descendiente

Tags: css, html5

Me encuentro aprendiendo CSS y tengo una duda en un selector si pudieran iluminarme un poco se los agradecería.

Procedo con el código para que le echen un vistazo:

```css
/* Esto es un selector descendiente */
    
div .pdescendiente{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="pdescendiente">Esto es un párrafo dentro de un div</p>
    <h1>Esto es un h1 dentro de un div</h1>
    <p>Este es otro p dentro de un div junto con un Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, impedit harum ipsam consectetur voluptatum optio doloremque? Laboriosam accusantium rem similique quidem sequi nisi, repellendus quisquam dicta delectus eligendi culpa ipsa!</p>
</div>
<!-- Tenemos el mismo párrafo, con la misma clase pero este no se 
    pinta por que estamos utilizando un selector descendiente para
    el otro-->
<p class="pdescendiente">Esto es un párrafo fuera de un div</p>
```

Mi duda es: ¿Qué pasaría si yo tuviera otro div, cómo identificaría el código css al div adecuado?, o ¿Lo hace mediante la clase siguiente?, en mi caso `.pdescendiente`. O en ese caso ¿Debería agregar un id o clase al div?.

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En CSS se aplican los estilos a todos los elementos que cumplan la condición del selector, en este caso, si tu declaras:

```css
div .pdescendiente{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

Ese estilo será aplicado a todos los elementos que tengan la clase `.pdescendiente` que estén dentro de un `div` (no necesariamente deben ser hijos directos de ese div).

Mientras más específico sea el selector, más prioridad tendrá el estilo, por ejemplo:

```css
div .pdescendiente {
    color: red;
}

div.ejemplo-clase .pdescendiente {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ejemplo-clase">

  <p class="pdescendiente">
    Ejemplo 2
  </p>
  
</div>

<div>

  <p class="pdescendiente">
    Ejemplo 1
  </p>
  
  <article>
    <p class="pdescendiente">
      Ejemplo 3
    </p>
  </article>
  
</div>
```

Ejemplo 2 será azul
Ejemplo 1 y Ejemplo 3 serán rojos